# Disable snapping to pixel grid

Tags: sketch-app

Is it possible to resize shapes or move shapes without aligning to pixel grid in Sketch 3?
I can use real numbers to set size like 34.5 but when resizing in convert size or position to integer numbers.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is, and it is quite simple.

Go to sketch > preferences (on a mac press cmd + ,), and under the first tab (General), uncheck the first box (says "pixel fitting: Fit layers and points to pixel bounds").

Done. :)

Hope it helped.

Take care,

Comment: didn't work for me...
the first option is 'fit layer and points to pixels' and it's already deselected. yet it still snaps to pixel.

Comment: This answer is outdated and appears to no longer work.

Comment: In the latest sketch, you have an option called Pixel Fitting preferences > Layers > Pixel Fittings uncheck the box and good

Answer (score 12):

You probably figured this out, but the snapping seems to be integral to the smart guides. If you turn off the smart guides, you can move and resize objects without them trying to snap align to everything else. View > Canvas > Show Smart Guides.

Comment: This answer is outdated and appears to no longer work.

Answer (score 7):

Its in the vector tool settings, called rounding. You can round to the nearest full pixel, half pixel, or none. I had a hard time finding it too.

Comment: Thanks Adam ! This worked for me. @Alan it's Above "Fills" and below "Corners" when you are editing a specific vector point. Press enter/return on a vector path to view each specific point.

Comment: Also, I have to move each point w/ the mouse to get it to snap to say 410 X 720 Y, instead of 409.432 X and 718.0932 Y. Then I move them with my keyboard arrows

Answer (score 4):

The answer, which says there's no way to disable snapping to pixel grid except for entering numbers manually, is wrong.  Hold down the ⌘ (command) key while dragging the object.  It will slide around smoothly.

Comment: This does not work. I'm in Sketch 55.1 fwiw. (Not sure why others aren't citing version numbers. Sketch seems to be changing stuff like this wildly between releases.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to disable snapping to pixel grid except for entering numbers manually like you have been doing. I confirmed this with Sketch support.