# Mirroring an arbitrary vector for symmetry in Sketch

Tags: vector, sketch-app

I'm trying to convert a raster logo to vector using Sketch. I've traced out part of the logo with an open vector, but only one-half of it. Now I want to mirror (flip horizontally) a copy of that open path, and join the two points. Here's the left half:

[image]

I copy and paste that, then flip the copy horizontally (I wish there was a mirror-across-axis feature). Then I drag it horizontally (with shift held down) until the left edge of the copy snaps to the right edge of the original. When this is done, the copy is 1/3 of a pixel lower than the original.

[image]

I can't figure out another way to accomplish this. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are on the right path (no pun intended). Maybe just move that right side to a whole pixel, then union and flatten, then set up a bunch of guides and fine tune.

Comment: have you tried making the one on the left a symbol and the one on the right an instance of it?

Comment: ...you could also use Illustrator if you have a license http://astutegraphics.com/blog/create-symmetrical-objects-adobe-illustrator/

Answer (score 1):

It seems the solution for your problem is [in this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/49618/16316):

> Go to sketch > preferences (on a mac press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), and under the first tab (General), uncheck the first box (says "Pixel fitting: Fit layers and points to pixel bounds").

This will allow your objects to align properly when mirroring.

Comment: This isn't the most elegant solution to this problem, but it is **the** solution. 90% of the time, having `Fit layers and points to pixel bounds` checked is what I want. This mirroring scenario (or really any type of illustration) is part of the 10% that it doesn't make sense.

**Note:** You can now find this option in `Sketch > Preferences > Layers`

Answer (score 1):

Select both paths and use 'align to bottom' in the alignment toolbar